# Group and Execute TestCase Scripts like testNG in mocha (or any other nodejs Testing framework)

Tags: node.js, automation, testng, mocha.js

I recently started coding in nodejs and using mocha as testing framework. Before mocha I was using testNG as automation framework.

Is it possible to group and execute test in node.js scripts similar to TestNG 
(something similar to suite.xml , parameterized testing)